# What is the probability of this number

Tags: probability, statistics

A friend of mine asked me what is the probability of getting the same number twice if I have a selection of

```
52 alphabets (A through Z and a through z lowercase)
10 numbers (0 through 9)
40 special characters that are on QWERTY keyboard
```

I said ok that should be

```
Probability = Event/Outcomes
Probability = 1/(52+10+40) = 0.0098
```

He then said if I had a string with length 14 then with a combination of above what is the probability of the same string happening twice i.e.

```
A$%B67@wQ32Z}(
A$%B67@wQ32Z}(
```

Each character in the string is chosen independently. I am lost.

Comment: Same principle.  Fix the first string.  The probability that the second one starts with thee same character is $\frac 1{48+10+40}=\frac 1{98}$.  Same for each character.  So....   (Note:  I am assuming that you are drawing characters uniformly at random *with replacement*).

Comment: There are 26 letters from A to Z.

Comment: @B.Goddard crap sorry thank you for the correction

Comment: Note:  I accepted your $48$ without thinking about it.  As remarked, it should of course be $52$.

Comment: But you should specify the rules.  I am assuming that each character is chosen independently of all other choices.  Thus $XXXXXXXXXXXX$ is a perfectly valid string.  But different assumptions will lead to different answers.

Comment: @lulu Each character in the string is chosen independently.

Comment: Fine, so then you have $12$ independent events each with the same probability.  By independence, all you have to do is multiply.

Comment: Phrased differently, there are $104^{12}$ equally probable strings of length $12$ and you are asking for the probability that your random selection is a particular one.

Comment: @lulu do you mean 1/(102) to the power of 14?

Comment: @SamB  Yes.  The length of the string in question.  Sorry for the typo.